# The "supported packages" in R

Tags: package-management, r

From http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/

> SUPPORTED PACKAGES
>
> A number of R packages are available from the Ubuntu repositories with
>   names starting with r-cran-. The following ones are kept up-to-date on
>   CRAN: all packages part of the r-recommended bundle, namely
>
> ```
>    r-cran-boot
>    r-cran-class
>    r-cran-cluster
>    r-cran-codetools
>    r-cran-foreign
>    r-cran-kernsmooth
>    r-cran-lattice
>    r-cran-mass
>    r-cran-matrix
>    r-cran-mgcv
>    r-cran-nlme
>    r-cran-nnet
>    r-cran-rpart
>    r-cran-spatial
>    r-cran-survival
> ```
>
> as well as
>
> ```
>    r-cran-rodbc
> ```
>
> **The other r-cran-* packages are updated with Ubuntu releases only.**
>   Users who need to update one of these R packages (say r-cran-foo)
>   should first make sure to obtain all the required build dependencies
>   with
>
> ```
>    sudo apt-get build-dep r-cran-foo
> ```
>
> Because **they rely on the installed version of R**, we also provide, on
>   an experimental basis, versions of the following packages as
>   up-to-date as the Ubuntu release allows:
>
> ```
>    littler
>    python-rpy
>    python-rpy-doc
> ```

What does the following two mean?

1. "The other r-cran-* packages are updated with Ubuntu releases only"

   How are they different from the previous "The following ones are kept up-to-date on CRAN"?
2. "they rely on the installed version of R".

   Does "they" refer to the previous "The other r-cran-* packages", or the next "the following packages"?

   Why is the reason for providing "versions of the following packages as up-to-date as the Ubuntu release allows"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How are they different from the previous "The following ones are kept up-to-date on CRAN"?

The recommended packages are maintained by the R Core team.
On CRAN there is special versioned directory for these packages. E.g. for R 3.0.2 it is [CRAN-mirror/src/contrib/3.2.0/Recommended/](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/3.2.0/Recommended/).

If you build R on your own, you can find a directory `src/library/Recommended` which is by default empty, but can be filled by using a helper script (`tools/rsync-recommended`).

> 2. "they rely on the installed version of R".

"they" refers to `littler` and `python-rpy`.

E.g. `rpy2` has the following [requirements](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/overview.html#requirements): Python 2.7, 3.3, or 3.4 and R 3.1+ (3.0 probably OK)